Python script with selenium works at local run, but doesn't on google colab
I'm working on a webscrapping script what function is to quote flight tickets on 'https://www.google.com/travel/flights', it works at my local machine, but when I try to run on Google Colab, it returns the following error message:
 "ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)".

Testing step by step the script almost all the code works on Colab, except a specific element during the executing of this code:

def seleciona_trecho(origem, destino):
    seleciona = webdriver.find_element("css selector","div.WKeVIb:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-   child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)")
    seleciona.click() # Clica no botão
    sleep(5)
    seleciona = webdriver.find_element("css selector","div.ND6Vic:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)")
    seleciona.send_keys(destino)   # Buscar os destinos a partir de uma lista
    seleciona.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    print("Destino inserido")


It seems that this element has a different CSS Selector when the website is opened on Colab.
Has anyone been through a situation like this and could help me?
    Changed Chrome options:
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') 
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')`


No noticeable changes in the performance.
